# About jquery and $document->addScriptDeclaration($js) by developing a plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, javascript, jquery, content

I seem to be having an issue when using jQuery in my plugin, which results in a blank page.
When I delete the last line `$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);`, the site display but the code doesn't work as expected.

Here is my plugin

```
<?php 

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class PlgContentEasySpoiler extends JPlugin 
{
    function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage('', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);       $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    }

    function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {
        if(!preg_match("@{spoiler}(.*){/spoiler}@sU", $article->text))
        {
            return;
        }
        if(preg_match_all("@{spoiler}(.*){/spoiler}@sU", $article->text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) > 0)
        {           
            foreach($matches[1] as $match)
            {
                $bgcolor                    = $this->params->get('bgcolor');
                $fontcolor                  = $this->params->get('fontcolor');
                $padding_top_bottom         = $this->params->get('padding_top_bottom');
                $padding_left_right         = $this->params->get('padding_left_right');
                $border_radius              = $this->params->get('border_radius');
                $anim_speed                 = $this->params->get('anim_speed');

                $html = '';    
                $spoiler = preg_replace('#<(/*)span[^>]*>#msi', '', $match);   
                $html .= '<span class="spoiler">'.$spoiler.'</span>';
                $article->text = preg_replace("@{spoiler}".$match."{/spoiler}@sU", $html, $article->text);
            }

            $css = 'a.reveal {
                background: '.$bgcolor.' !important; 
                padding:  '.$padding_top_bottom.'px '.$padding_left_right.'px !important; 
                border-radius:'.$border_radius.'px !important; 
                box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
                -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
                -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
                color: '.$fontcolor.' !important;

            }'."\n";

            JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration($css);

            JHtml::_('jquery.framework');           
            JHtml::_('script', 'easyspoiler/js/easyspoiler.js', false, true, false, false, true);           
            $js = <<<SCRIPTHERE
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery(document.body).EasySpoiler({
                        'anim_speed':       
                        '$anim_speed',
                    });             
                }); SCRIPTHERE;             
            $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);                               
        }
    } 
}
```

and also the XML file

```
<files>
     <filename plugin="easyspoiler">easyspoiler.php</filename>
     <filename plugin="easyspoiler">index.html</filename>
</files>
<media folder="media" destination="easyspoiler">
     <folder>js</folder>
</media>
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_easyspoiler.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_easyspoiler.ini</language>
    <language tag="de-DE">language/de-DE/de-DE.plg_content_easyspoiler.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="de-DE">language/de-DE/de-DE.plg_content_easyspoiler.ini</language>
</languages>

<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="EASYSPOILER">   
            <field name="bgcolor" type="color" default="#fff" 
            label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BACKGROUND_COLOR"    
            description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BACKGROUND_COLOR_DESC" />
            <field name="fontcolor" type="color" default="#000" 
            label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_FONT_COLOR"  
            description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_FONT_COLOR_DESC" />
            <field name="padding_top_bottom" type="text" default="2" label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_TOP_BOTTOM" description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_TOP_BOTTOM_DESC" filter="integer" />
            <field name="padding_left_right" type="text" default="5" label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_LEFT_RIGHT" description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_LEFT_RIGHT_DESC" filter="integer" />
            <field name="border_radius" type="text" default="5" label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BORDER_RADIUS" description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BORDER_RADIUS_DESC" filter="integer" />
            <field name="border_shadow" type="text" default="5" label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BORDER_SHADOW" description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_BORDER_SHADOW_DESC" filter="integer" />
            <field name="anim_speed" type="text" default="500" label="PLG_EASYSPOILER_ANIM_SPEED" description="PLG_EASYSPOILER_ANIM_SPEED_DESC" filter="integer" />
         </fieldset>         
    </fields>
 </config>
```

Comment: your document variable is not declared inside that function. add $document = JFactory::getDocument();

Answer (score 2):

$document is only declared in the __construct scope.

You have to declare it before using it in onContentPrepare scope.

Alternatively, you can call addScriptDeclaration in the same way than you do with addStyleDeclaration:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would refrain from using `$document = ...` and then go on to use `JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration($css);` because you're calling the class and fucntion twice and thus slowing down the process.

All you need to do is define the variable once inside the `onContentPrepare` function and then add your declarations like so:

```
function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
{
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    $css = 'YOUR CSS CODE';
    $js  = 'YOUR JS CODE';

    $document->addStyleDeclaration($css);
    $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format your script variable to this:

```
$js = <<<SCRIPTHERE
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(document.body).EasySpoiler({
       'anim_speed':       
       '$anim_speed',
     });             
   }); 
SCRIPTHERE;
```

When using heredoc syntax, the closing identifier (`SCRIPTHERE;`) must begin in the first column, i.e. it should not be indented.

This if from the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> **Warning** It is very important to note that the line with the closing
>   identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;).
>   That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and
>   there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.
>   It's also important to realize that the first character before the
>   closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating
>   system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing
>   delimiter must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken
>   and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a
>   closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper
>   closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a
>   parse error will result at the last line.

Change that line and see if that solves anything.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the `preg_match()` condition block should be removed entirely.  You can just use `!preg_match_all()` to perform your early `return`.  `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` can be omitted because it is the default flag value.

Your `$this->params->get()` lines shouldn't be declared in the loop because they will only overwrite the variables with the same data (over and over).

Instantiating `$html` should be done prior to entering the loop so that you don't inadvertently delete the previous iteration's text.

The `m` and `s` pattern modifiers in your `$spoiler` replacement call is unnecessary because you don't have any anchors (`^` or `$`) or dots (`.`) in your pattern.  I'm not really sure of the coding intent behind purging all of the inner `<span>` tags, but I'll just follow your posted code.  (your `preg_replace("@{spoiler}".$match."{/spoiler}@sU"` pattern *could have* contained special characters that would cause the regex engine to fail.)

After further consideration, I reckon I'd omit the `preg_match_all()` and looping task entirely.  `preg_replace_callback()` can do everything in one step.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ioknn)

The heredoc syntax seemed to be more trouble than it is worth for you, I'll swap them out for double-quoted string declarations.

```
function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
{
    $article->text = preg_replace_callback('~{spoiler}(.*?){/spoiler}~s', 
        function($m) {
            return '<span class="spoiler">' .
                   preg_replace('~</?span[^>]*>~i', '', $m[1]) .
                   '</span>';
        }, $article->text, -1, $count);

    if (!$count) return;

    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    $bgcolor            = $this->params->get('bgcolor');
    $fontcolor          = $this->params->get('fontcolor');
    $padding_top_bottom = $this->params->get('padding_top_bottom');
    $padding_left_right = $this->params->get('padding_left_right');
    $border_radius      = $this->params->get('border_radius');
    $anim_speed         = $this->params->get('anim_speed');

    $css = "a.reveal {\n
              background: {$bgcolor} !important;\n
              padding: {$padding_top_bottom)px {$padding_left_right}px !important;\n
              border-radius: {$border_radius}px !important;\n
              box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;\n
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;\n
              -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;\n
              color: {$fontcolor} !important;\n
            }\n";
    $document->addStyleDeclaration($css);

    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');           
    JHtml::_('script', 'easyspoiler/js/easyspoiler.js', false, true, false, false, true);           
    $js = "jQuery(document).ready(function() {\n
                jQuery(document.body).EasySpoiler({\n
                    'anim_speed': '{$anim_speed}'\n
                });\n
            });\n";
    $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);                               
}
```